# PHP array print unexpected output format

Tags: php, arrays, io

I am trying to print an array in reverse order in PHP 7, but it is printed in a strange way.

```
<?php

$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
fscanf($handle,"%d",$n);
$arr_temp = fgets($handle);
$arr = explode(" ",$arr_temp);
array_walk($arr,'intval');

$output = "";

for($i = $n - 1; $i>=0; $i--){
    $output .= $arr[$i] . " ";
}

print($output);

?>
```

With the input:

```
4
1 2 3 4
```

I get the output:

```
4
 3 2 1
```

Why is that?

Comment: You know of `array_reverse` and `implode`, right?

Comment: What is `$n`???

Comment: Maybe try to `trim` it.

Comment: @AbraCadaver the number of items in the array

Comment: @JonStirling actually, I didn't. Thank you!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Its one of those dodgy pass by reference functions in php [fscanf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php) which does different things depending on how many arguments it has

Comment: @R.Chappell - I noticed that. These kind of things makes me cringe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by CodeBrauer, the solution is to `trim` the input string before calling the `explode` function:

```
$arr = explode(" ", trim($arr_temp));
```